Is sire (しれ) attested in Old Japanese texts as a pronoun?
According to A History of the Japanese Language, si is attested in Old Japanese texts as a third person pronoun:



Person
Genitive
Non-genitive
Combining




1st
(w)aga
(w)are
(w)a


2nd
naga
nare
na


3rd
siga
sire?
si


Who
taga
tare
ta



Most these forms have been recorded in modern dicitionaries, with quotations from Old Japanese texts, except sire. So is sire found in any extant Old Japanese text at all?

(o2 is reconstructed phonetically by Bjarke Frellesvig as /o/ and by Alexander Vovin as /ǝ/.)

Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", page 250):

2.2.8 Third Person Pronoun si
This pronoun in Old Japanese occurs exclusively with the following possessive case marker -ᵑga, with both animate and inanimate referents.

Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", pages 138-139) includes this speculation about origin of si:

The 3rd person si is used both with animate and inanimate reference. Si is not used much, however; 3rd person reference is mostly expressed by the non-proximal demonstrative so, from which si is diachronically derived (explaining why si alone among the short forms does not form compounds): *sɨ-i > si.

(That /ɨ/ is high central unrounded vowel.)
Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", page 256):

Looking at this text, one can clearly see that si-ᵑga appears to be a textual variant of sǝ-ᵑga, a third person pronoun possessive form also attested in Classical Japanese (Vovin 2003: 114), which is derived from the demonstrative sǝ- ‘that.’

Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", page 258):

Besides the special form sǝ-ᵑga, mentioned above in KK 101, there is also a special form sǝ-ne-ᵑga and sǝ-ne, attested just once each in the same text. These forms appear to be parallel to the second person pronoun special form na-ne (see section 2.2.5):
曾泥賀母登曾泥米
sǝ-ne-ᵑga mǝtǝ sǝ-ne mɛ
it-?-POSS root it-? bud
its roots, its buds (KK 11)

Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", page 258):

Comparative Data
Level A: Other Japonic
A1: Eastern Old Japanese
There is no second or third person pronoun si in Eastern Old Japanese, but the genitive form sǝ-nǝ ‘it-GEN’ of third person sǝ- ‘it’ is attested once, and there is also one example of the accusative form sǝ-wo, which does not occur in Western Old Japanese.
曾能可抱与吉爾
sǝ-nǝ kapo yǝ-ki-ni
it-GEN face good-ATTR-LOC
its face is good, but [it does not move forward] (MYS 14.3411)
比登豆麻等安是可曾乎伊波牟
pitǝ-ⁿ-duma tǝ aⁿze ka sǝ-wo ip-am-u
person-GEN-wife DV why IP she-ACC say-TENT-ATTR
Why should [I] call her the wife of another? (MYS 14.3472)

Eastern Old Japanese is in some ways more conservative than Western Old Japanese (centred on region of capital Nara). It would seem that si-ᵑga developed from sǝ-ᵑga in Western Old Japanese, but sire did not develop from sǝre.
And finally, Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", pages 142) has this theory about pre-Old Japanese:

3.8.4 Basic pre-Old Japanese pronominal system
Based on the OJ forms, a simple and basic pronominal system may be posited for pre-OJ, see (139), with a 'speaker – non-speaker – interrogative' system for both the personal and the demonstrative pronouns, and including wa as an indefinite:
(139)
Personal
speaker 1st a
non-speaker 2nd na
indefinite wa
interrogative 'who' ta
Demonstrative
speaker proximal ko
non-speaker non-proximal so
interrogative 'which' i-
Reflexive ono


Coincidentally, kare and kanozyo personal pronouns in Modern Japanese have also developed from distal demonstrative pronouns, which lost initial k in many forms:
kare → are
kano → ano
kanata → anata

What do the abbreviations POSS and GEN mean? If ᵑga is POSS but nǝ is GEN, does that mean POSS is used by Vovin for humans and nǝ for non-humans, like Frellesvig suggests?

@Vun-HughVaw For unclear reasons, Vovin called ᵑga possessive case marker, and nǝ genitive case marker. He also wrote: 「The claim that -ᵑga follows animate nouns while -nǝ follows inanimates does not hold true, although there is a certain tendency towards a more frequent usage of -ᵑga after personal names and titles. It looks like that it probably was the case in proto-Japonic, if we take into consideration the archaic distribution still preserved in Ryukyuan (see below).」
